# Ubuntu 20.10 - second SSD hard drive disconnects after a while (ceph storage cluster)

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

I have an extra ssd hard drive installed inside an Intel NUC. It is part of a Ceph storage cluster. After operating for a while, it disappears as far as Ubuntu is concerned.

I'm able to get it back by physically unplugging and replugging the ssd. I've checked the plug and seems to be connected securely.

Any ideas on what the problem is or how to fix/debug?

This shows the drive connected at `sda1` after it has initially been connected.

```
user@nuc-master:~$ lsblk -f
NAME                                                        FSTYPE         LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1                                                      LVM2_member          bDQONL-4vEW-RGRK-0Abk-CiP4-rdGF-b0dx3T
  └─ceph--6e62d365--fb27--4625--81dd--7303da5db950-osd--data--a9054cfa--03d4--4a2e--aa88--13136614dc65
                                                            ceph_bluestore
```

I have three machines configured in the same way. The hard drives on the other machines work as expected.